# How can I invoke a dynamic external dll

Tags: c#, dll

In C#, I want to call a method in an external DLL with signature `bool IsValid(string)`,
but the name of the dll is coming from input as a string.

How can I:

1. Call the external method?
2. Implement the `IsValid` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the external DLL managed or unmanaged?

If it's a managed DLL, [`Assembly.LoadFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx) will let you load it and call the function from a class within it.

For unmanaged DLLs, @lcfseth's link is the right way to go.

Answer (score 3):

for first question i found this answer:

```
string path = ApplicationMapPath+ objDLLName + ".dll";
System.Reflection.Assembly a = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(path);
Type t = a.GetType("<namespace>.<Class>");
object instance = a.CreateInstance("<namespace>.<Class>");

MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("<FuncName>");// Call the method
object res = m.Invoke(instance, new object[] { txtBox.Text }); // Get the result here
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is by using the Win32 library and particularity the LoadLibrary API function.
Here's a link that should help you get started:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27298/Dynamic-Invoke-C-DLL-function-in-C